# Exercise on curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

"Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular curve and let $\alpha:I\rightarrow C$ be its natural parametrization. Consider $p=\alpha(s_0)$ and define $\varphi_p:I\rightarrow C$ as $\varphi_p(s)=\parallel\alpha(s)-p\parallel^2 \forall s\in I$. Prove that f is differentiable (I mean $C^\infty$) in a neighborhood of $s_0$ and express the curvature $k(p)$ of $C$ in $p$ in terms of the function $\varphi_p$ and its derivatives."

I solved the first part of the problem, showing that $\varphi_p$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $s_0$, but I'm having difficulties solving the second part: I've found out an expression for the curvature, which is $k(s)= \frac{\varphi_p''(s)-2}{\sqrt{4\varphi_p(s)-\varphi_p'(s)^2}}$, by computing the derivatives of $\varphi_p$, observing that $\varphi_p(s)=((\alpha(s)-p)\cdot N(s))^2+((\alpha(s)-p)\cdot T(s))^2=((\alpha(s)-p)\cdot N(s))^2+\frac{\varphi_p'(s)^2}{4}$ and assuming that $(\alpha(s)-p)\cdot N(s)>0$ (where $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ denote respectively the tangent and the normal unit vector). However, it is clear that the expression written above is valid only if $s\neq s_0$.
My idea was to prove that $k(s)$ can be extended for continuity in $s=s_0$, but applying De L'Hôpital's rule or using Taylor's approximations seems to be useless... Can you give me any hint?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's probably easiest to use the local canonical form of $\alpha$ at $s=s_0$. You will need a higher derivative of $\varphi_p$ than you've computed.